# How to change a column in a data frame to string after mapping with a dictionary

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to convert the column in my data frame to string so i can use it in FeatureHasher. As feature 
Hasher takes only string

[Before - the states column is in numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mleei.png)

[After - the states column changed to string but the data type is object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIVXx.png)

The codes I used:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/My Drive/data_feature_engineering/VEHICLE - Copy.csv")
data.head(10)

states = {1:'Alabama',2 :'Alaska',4: 'Arizona',5: 'Arkansas',6: 'California',8: 'Colorado',9: 'Connecticut',10: 'Delaware',11: 'District of Columbia',12: 'Florida',13: 'Georgia',
          15: 'Hawaii',16:'Idaho', 17: 'Illinois', 18: 'Indiana',19: 'Iowa',20: 'Kansas',21: 'Kentucky',22: 'Louisiana',23: 'Maine',24: 'Maryland',25: 'Massachusetts',
          26: 'Michigan',27: 'Minnesota',28: 'Mississippi',29: 'Missouri',30: 'Montana',31: 'Nebraska',32: 'Nevada',33: 'New Hampshire',34: 'New Jersey',35: 'New Mexico',
          36: 'New York', 37: 'North Carolina', 38: 'North Dakota', 39: 'Ohio', 40: 'Oklahoma', 41: 'Oregon',  42: 'Pennsylvania', 43: 'Puerto Rico', 44: 'Rhode Island',
          45: 'South Carolina', 46: 'South Dakota', 47: 'Tennessee', 48: 'Texas', 49: 'Utah', 50: 'Vermont', 52:'Virgin Islands', 51: 'Virginia',53: 'Washington',
          54: 'West Virginia', 55: 'Wisconsin', 56: 'Wyoming'}

sample = data[['State']]
sample['State'] = sample['State'].replace(states)
sample
sample.State.dtype
```

[The data type of the new string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fqty.png)

I even dont know the reason for the warning message it shows

**P.S:**

Now I tried the same code in my jupyter notebook running from my pc. 
My pandas version is 1.0.1
I am still getting the warning. The data type is an object

[Still getting the same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJOk.png)

Comment: which version of pandas are you using? the datatype string wasn't introduced into pandas dataframes until version 1.0 so if you are using anything prior to that a string is a type "object" in pandas.you can do `print(pd.__version__)` to get the version. If it is <1.0 dtype object is expected for a string.

Comment: I am using google Colab
 Pandas version  0.25.3

Comment: Is there a way to upgrade pandas in colab ?